# count specific lines in specific files in a folder

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly new to ruby but this is testing me

I want to count all the lines in any file that ends in bowtie.txt in a folder

The lines have to start with a number of varying length followed by a '+' or a '-' (with or without whitespace inbetween. Sometimes the lines are wrapped but I don't know if this matters).

I want to then create a hash that stores the filename with the count associated with it.

I've got as far I think as looping through the directory to select the files out and then counting the number of lines in that file but how do I then create the hash and return it?

The file data looks like:

```
0   +   chr12   129402816   ACACAGGGAGGGGAATAACACACACTGGGACCTGTCAGGAGAGGGTAGGGCTGGGGGCATCAGGAGAGCATCAGGAAAAATAGCTAATGCATGCTGGGCT    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    0   
2   -   chr5    93625939    TCAACCTGTCATCTACATTAGGTATTTCTCCTAATGCTATCCCTCCCCTAGCCCCCCACCACCCAACAGACCCTGGTGTGTGATGTTCCCCTCCCTGTGT    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    0   5:T>C
5   +   chr3    155023119   ACACAGGGAGGGGAACATCACACACCGGGGCCTGTAGTGGGGGTGAGGGGCAAGAGGAGGAATAGCATTAGGAGAAATACCTAATGTAGATGACCGGTTG    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    0   
7   +   chr2    22818055    ACACAGGGAGGGGAAAAACACACACTGGGGCTTCTCAGGGGTGGTGGGGGGAGAGCATCAGGATAAATAGCTAATGCATGCAGGGCTTAATACCTAGGTG    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    0   
8   +   chr3    131206106   ACACAGGGAGGGGAACATCACACACCAGGCCCTGTCAGCGGTGAGGGGCTGGGGGAGGGATAGCATTAAGAGAAATACCTAATATAAATGACGAGTTGAT    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    0   8:C>A
10  +   chrX    108455592   ACACAGGGAGGGGAACATCACACACCAGGGCCTGTCGGGCAGTGGGGGGGCAAAGGGAGGGATTAAGTCATACACCCAATGCATGTGGGGCTTAAAACCC    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    0   7:A>G
11  -   chr2    31936302    ACCCATTAACTCGTCATTTACATTAGGTATATCTCCTAATGCTATCCCTCCCCCCACCCCACAACAGGCCCCCCGGTGTGTGATGTTCCCCTCCCTGTGT    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    0   7:T>C
```

This is what I am trying to get at the end

```
blablabla.bowtie.txt : 27998
blablafsfds.bowtie.txt : 25987
etc
```

This is my attempt at the code:

```
Dir[File.join('/Volumes/SeagateBackupPlusDriv/SequencingRawFiles/TumourOesophagealOCCAMS/SequencingScripts/3finalcounts', '*.bowtie.txt')].each |file| do
  puts File.open(file) { |f| f.grep(/^[0-9]*.\+|\-/).count }
end
```

Comment: So what error did you get with your current code?

Comment: The code error said rb:2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block and rb:4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input BUT I also don't know how to create the hash to give the final output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, since I have no input files, but likely working:

```
# `Dir[]` expects it’s own format
#                                ⇓ will inject results into hash
Dir['/Volumes/.../*.bowtie.txt'].inject({}) do |memo, file|
  memo[file] = File.readlines(file).select do |line| 
                 line =~ /^[0-9]+\s*(\+|\-)/ # only those, matching
               end.count
  memo
end
```

Additional references: [`IO#readlines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines), [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

Comment: I get a rb:2:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
The first line is Dir['/Volumes/SeagateBackupPlusDriv/SequencingRawFiles/TumourOesophagealOCCAMS/SequencingScripts/3finalcounts/*.bowtie.txt'].inject({}) do |memo, file|

Comment: Does `Dir['/Volumes/.../*.bowtie.txt']` return an array as expected?

Comment: should the array output into the terminal I'm running from. If so, I dont get a returned array

Comment: ?help. seems to have gone  cold

Comment: I removed one file that was empty and causing an error. Now I get one hash but then I get the same error

Comment: OK I think it was because I was using puts memo without a last memo so it failed. Sorted now. Thanks